# Time Entry - Usability

Tags: html, web-applications, user-interface, usability

What is the conventional wisdom around entering times into a web app? I've seen both free form fields, and drop downs.

I have a user right now arguing that drop downs are easier to use, despite the fact that you have 18 options between 3 drop downs. I feel that using a text field (and PHP strtotime()) that I can eliminate all of that hassle, and give the user some flexibility.

I can't seem to find any documentation on tests that point me in either direction, other than someone mentioning Hick's Law on a forum. Can anyone point me to something and/or give definite answers?

Comment: How do you get 18 options between 3 dropdowns? Isn't it 12 * 60 * 2 options? Or 2 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 2? Or at least 12 * 24 * 2 if you only resolve time to the nearest 5 minutes?

Comment: You need to provide me one piece of additional info & I will answer your question...what time is being captured? Is it (i) the current time or (ii) some time in the past or future?

When it comes to usability, context of use will answer most questions.

Comment: Future Time - if it was current time I'd just make a timestamp behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text box entry is without a doubt faster than combo boxes. A rudimentary GOMS-KLM analysis shows that.

Users generally know how to type a time so user error is not a major concern assuming you provide a wide range of tolerance for the format (e.g., accepting 2pm, 2:00 PM, 0200p, 14.00, 14 as all the same). It also helps to use Javascript or equivalent to suppress all letters except ‘a’, ‘p’, and autocomplete the ‘m’. Autocorrect any symbol to ‘:’.

Users sometimes forget the AM or PM, leading them to schedule a meeting at 2:00am. You may want to include a dropdown or option buttons for AM/PM alone to cue the user, while still accepting entry of it in the text box and automatically selecting the dropdown/option button accordingly.

If you have to convince just one user, mockup up both a dropdown and text box versions and sit with him/her with a stopwatch and time him/her entering times. When you show that the textbox takes about 2-3 seconds, while dropdowns take over 9 seconds, that should do it.

Comment: Great reply Michael. Do you have any links to support this?

Comment: There's a pretty good summary on how to do a GOMS-KLM analysis at:
http://phillips.rmc.ca/courses/459-2008/lectures/05-goms-klm.html
Although he doesn't specifically mention time, Nielsen discusses his studies revealing misuse of dropdowns at:
http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20001112.html
http://www.useit.com/alertbox/annoyances.html

Comment: GOMS is great at telling you how fast people can mouse/type through an interface. It leaves aside the task that the user is actually doing, and how they are thinking about the task. If there are mental translations that need to occur (e.g. the user is thinking 'twenty minutes before quitting time' and they have to translate to '4:40pm') that can slow down the user a lot, or add a lot of effort.

GOMS is a good tool, but it's not enough.

Answer (score 1):

I despise drop downs for times, but that is just me.  I feel they slow the end user down.
You should free form it and then format it the way you want.  Also just set up some validations to ensure people are entering correct data into the field.

But yes I agree with you.

Comment: @JonH You would have to do the same validation regardless of the UI element used. @Cory Dee I do prefer freeform to drop downs as well.

Comment: @JonH - Yes if the dropdowns are pre-populated - what if I write a form that posts data to your form's `action` URL? What if I decide to fill in my form with the hour "fizzbuzz"? Might sound goofy, but users are not to be trusted.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger - That is only if I am taking that value from the drop down and passing it to a URL.  What if I am simply taking this value and storing in a db?  Users cannot make edits to that drop down.  Unless the originator of that question mentioned he is passing his data off to another URL.

Comment: I absolutely hate it when web page forces me to scroll through numbers from 1900 to 2009 whe selecting my date of birth.